# What do we get from OutputResponse[sys {u1,u2}]?

Tags: signal-processing

I understand what OutputResponse is doing in the first two examples below.

```
sys=TransferFunctionModel[{{{1+z}},0.1-0.667*z+z^2},z,SamplingPeriod->1];
u1=Join[{-1},ConstantArray[0,17]];
ListPlot[OutputResponse[sys, u1]]
(* result is not displayed *)
```

Second example:

```
u2=Join[ConstantArray[0,8],{1},ConstantArray[0,9]];
ListPlot[OutputResponse[sys, u2]]
(* result is not displayed *)
```

Next I see that  OutputResponse[sys, {u1}]  gives the exact same result OutputResponse[sys, {u1,u2}].

```
response1=OutputResponse[sys,{u1}];
response12=OutputResponse[sys,{u1,u2}];
response1===response12
(* True *)
```

The last line of the OutputResponse usage message says,
OutputResponse[sys, {u1, ..., um} ]  gives the output response for multiple inputs ui.

So why are response1 and response12 above exactly the same?  Also, please explain a  simple example that uses this feature of OutputResponse where the result is affected by both u1 and u2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no expert in Mathematica's control systems, but I *think* the reason is that your system is single input single output, and Mathematica is simply ignoring additional inputs in the list. Hence when you give input as `{u1,u2,u3}`, it is just using `u1` each time.

```
sys=TransferFunctionModel[{{{1+z}},0.1-0.667*z+z^2},z,SamplingPeriod->1];
ss = StateSpaceModel[sys]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It might be easier to see this for a continuous time system. Here is an single input single output system

```
sys1 = TransferFunctionModel[{{1/(s^2 + s)}}, s]
ss = MinimalStateSpaceModel[StateSpaceModel[sys1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now lets ask for the output response for some input

```
 OutputResponse[sys1, {Sin[t]}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now let do as you did and give it multiple inputs

```
 OutputResponse[sys1, {Sin[t], Cos[t], t}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Same output. Because the system is single input, it used only first input in the list, which is `Sin[t]` only.

> Also, please explain a simple example that uses this feature of
> OutputResponse where the result is affected by both u1 and u2.

You would need a 2 input system. Here is an example

```
sys2 = TransferFunctionModel[{{2/(1 + s), s/(s - 1)}}, s]
ss = MinimalStateSpaceModel[StateSpaceModel[sys2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now

```
 OutputResponse[sys2, {Sin[t]}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And

```
 OutputResponse[sys2, {Sin[t], Cos[t]}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now it used the second input `Cos[t]` because the system supports 2 inputs, and the output now is different from when one input was given.